# How to remove cross site scripting?

Tags: asp.net, xss

I am attaching a pdf file in a mail that i have to sent in asp.net . It is showing cross site scripting .How can we remove this and make it safe scripting.

Below is the line in which it is showing cross site scripting :-

```
attach.Text = "<a href='" + TotalPath + "' target='_blank' align='left'>" + attachfile + "</a>";
```

In the above line ,
TotalPath is the path from which I am giving the path which is as follows:-

```
string TotalPath = "http://c0007445.itcs.xxx.com:90/Comp/Attachments/" + attachfile;
```

and attachfile is the file which is to be attached , defined as

```
string attachfile = pproid + "_" + PeriodShort + ".pdf";
```

Comment: What is show that "cross site scripting" ?

Comment: @Aristos    attach.Text = "<a href='" + TotalPath + "' target='_blank' align='left'>" + attachfile + "</a>"; this line is showing cross site scipting(XSS).